# My primary BIND server does not answer authoritatively, the secondary works as expected. What is wrong?

Tags: dns, bind

I seem to have an issue with my BIND9 setup.

My first server answers (ns1.m2osw.com) response is not authoritative (no "aa" flag). Here is the output I currently get:

```
$ dig @ns1.m2osw.com m2osw.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.18-Ubuntu <<>> @ns1.m2osw.com m2osw.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50582
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;m2osw.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
m2osw.com.      3600    IN  A   165.232.146.181

;; Query time: 24 msec
;; SERVER: 165.232.146.181#53(165.232.146.181)
;; WHEN: Wed Mar 22 17:30:34 PDT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54
```

On the other hand, my secondary server, which is the slave, returns an answer with the "aa" flag set as expected:

```
$ dig @ns2.m2osw.com m2osw.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.18-Ubuntu <<>> @ns2.m2osw.com m2osw.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48685
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 192861169293b4a6ced2041c641b9daf4141e9f698003f54 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;m2osw.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
m2osw.com.      3600    IN  A   165.232.146.181

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
m2osw.com.      3600    IN  NS  ns1.m2osw.com.
m2osw.com.      3600    IN  NS  ns2.m2osw.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.m2osw.com.      3600    IN  A   165.232.146.181
ns2.m2osw.com.      3600    IN  A   96.67.192.225

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 96.67.192.225#53(96.67.192.225)
;; WHEN: Wed Mar 22 17:30:39 PDT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 150
```

The settings are very similar except for the zone where one server says "master" (ns1) and the other says "slave" (ns2). If anything, I would have expected the slave to answer without the "aa" flag.

Here is the master zone definition:

```
zone "m2osw.com" {
  type master;
  file "/var/lib/bind/m2osw.com.zone";
  allow-transfer { trusted-servers; };
  check-names warn;
  max-journal-size 2M;
};
```

And the corresponding slave:

```
zone "m2osw.com" {
  type slave;
  masters { list-of-masters; };
  allow-transfer { none; };
  file "/var/cache/bind/m2osw.com.zone";
};
```

Also both servers have recursion ON for the other:

```
allow-recursion { trusted-servers; };
```

I've been changing my list of domain names many times and I can say that it generally works well except for that missing "aa" flag...

---

#### UPDATE

Here is the top of the zone file:

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 3600
m2osw.com IN SOA ns1.m2osw.com. hostmaster.m2osw.com. (242 10800 180 1209600 300)
    NS ns1.m2osw.com.
    NS ns2.m2osw.com.
    MX 10   mail.m2osw.com.
    A   165.232.146.181
$ORIGIN m2osw.com.
mail    A   165.232.146.181
ns1     A   165.232.146.181
ns2     A   96.67.192.225
www     A   165.232.146.181
...other TXT & A fields...
```

if that helps.

Comment: I would guess incorrect SOA in `/var/lib/bind/m2osw.com.zone`. Your logs should tell you although you may have to increase the verbosity. Digging SOA on both ns's, ns1 does not contain ns records and is one point ahead in the serial number compared to ns2. So I would still assume error in ns1.

Comment: @Bib I added the start of the file to the question. I'm not sure how else it would be defined? Testing with higher verbosity level now.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the zone file.

Notice $ORIGIN is set to root at the first line, yet you are declaring 2 NS's, an MX & an A record against it. The `$ORIGIN m2osw.com.` must go above those records.

I would have thought your logs would show an error here.

It should become:

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 3600
m2osw.com IN SOA ns1.m2osw.com. hostmaster.m2osw.com. (242 10800 180 1209600 300)
$ORIGIN m2osw.com.
    NS ns1.m2osw.com.
    NS ns2.m2osw.com.
    MX 10   mail.m2osw.com.
    A   165.232.146.181
www A   165.232.146.181
...other TXT & A fields...
```

Alternatively, to reduce such errors, try:

```
$ORIGIN m2osw.com.
$TTL 3600
@ IN SOA ns1.m2osw.com. hostmaster.m2osw.com. (242 10800 180 1209600 300)
  NS ns1.m2osw.com.
  NS ns2.m2osw.com.
  MX 10   mail.m2osw.com.
A   165.232.146.181
www A   165.232.146.181
...other TXT & A fields...
```

Or even...

```
$ORIGIN @
$TTL 3600
@ IN SOA ns1.m2osw.com. hostmaster.m2osw.com. (242 10800 180 1209600 300)
  NS ns1.m2osw.com.
  NS ns2.m2osw.com.
  MX 10   mail.m2osw.com.
A   165.232.146.181
www A   165.232.146.181
...other TXT & A fields...
```

And you may need to update the serial number.

Comment: Hmmm... that didn't work. I can now see the "aa" flag from the server pinging itself but from the secondary it does not show the "aa" when querying the primary. I also made sure that the IP was on my domain name provider and it looks fine there. It's just a tad bit better right now...

Comment: You still have an error in your zone file. There are no records listed within it. I assume you do have `ns1 A 165.232.146.181` & `ns2 A 96.67.192.225` records listed. You need to post the head of the zone file on ns1.

Comment: I would also advise you to strip the zone file down to just the three NS & MX entries plus the www one and see what happens.

Comment: Well... this is weird... I tested from another server which has no DNS at all and all answers have the "aa" flag. So it is considered authoritative from the outside, but not from the slave server! Weird.